# JasperReports Server to generate by RESTful calls and json returns

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am looking for possibilities to generate *JasperReports*'s reports through REST calls. The idea is to have three simple steps -

1. Write a RESTful GET services which can take variable parameters and return json output.
2. Generate report in jasper
3. Use built in capabilities to print, schedule and email reports using jasper.

I looked around in internet and couldn't find if that is possible. Please point any suitable example if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer by order:

1- Yes you can call the report with rest using parameters and get the json output. [jasperserver guide to web service](https://d2553lapexsdrl.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide_2.pdf) will guide you very well.

2- The rest call can generate the report in jasper.

3- You can use built in quartz and mail capabilities to schedule and email the reports as well. You can consult this [link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-report-scheduler) for that.